# What AI conferences in Europe should I consider submitting papers to explaining the ongoing work on RefPerSys?

Tags: ai-design, research, papers, meta-learning

https://afia.asso.fr/journee-hommage-j-pitrat/ is a seminar on March 6th, 2020, in Paris (France, European Union), in honor of the late [Jacques Pitrat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Pitrat), who advocated during all his professional life a meta-knowledge and reflective approach. (You need to register to attend that seminar).

Pitrat's blog is available (in spring 2020) on http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/ (and some snapshot of his [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/?s=CAIA) system is downloadable [here](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/caia-su-24feb2016.tar.bz2) - but no documentation; however you might try to type `L EDITE` on stdin to `caia`). He wrote the [*Artificial Beings : the conscience of a conscious machine*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470611791) book describing the software architecture of, and the motivations for (some previous version of) CAIA. See also this [*A Step toward an Artificial Artificial Intelligence Scientist*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2117/9600b3f05c0af399f9acbfc6e7b6d24daf03.pdf) paper by J.Pitrat.

What AI conferences (or [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence) workshops) in Europe should I consider submitting papers to explaining the ongoing work on [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.%20org/)?

That [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project (open source, open science, work-in-progress, with contact information) is explicitly following J.Pitrat's meta-knowledge approach. Feel free to follow or join that ambitious open-source (actually [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)) project.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to as many as possible. Average accept rate of papers is around 20%. You can find the best conferences on [AI & ML Event](https://aiml.events).